# error: attempted to update component that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React, I'm having trouble rendering my app due to this error. It's seems the data that I'm trying to render as elements won't render due to trying to set state when unmounted?

I'm not sure how I'm getting this error, as I'm setting the state of `Data` in `componentDidMount`.

How can I fix this issue?

> error: attempted to update component that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount)

```
class Profile extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    handleLogout: PropTypes.func,
    user: PropTypes.object,
  };

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerVisible: true,
    title: 'Profile',
  };

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    data: [],
    loading: true

    };
  }

componentDidMount() {

  fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8080/combined", { method: 'get' })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({data: data,});

    })
   .catch(function(err) {
     // 
   })
}

 render() {

    const { user } = this.props;
    let email;

    if (user) {
      email = user.rows[0].ACCTNO;
    }
    return (
      <ContentWrapper>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image style={styles.header} source={images.profileHeader} />
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <Avatar email={email} style={styles.avatar} />
             {
   this.state.data.map(function(rows, i){
         this.setState({mounted:  true});

    return(
      <View key={i}>
        <Text>{rows.FIRSTNAME}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  })
}            <Text style={styles.email}>{_.capitalize(email)}</Text>

            <Button
              title="Log out"
              icon={{ name: 'logout-variant', type: 'material-community' }}
              onPress={this.logout}
              style={styles.logoutButton}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </ContentWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: Your map function is why the error is occurring. You call setState inside render().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your render function, you're calling `this.setState({mounted:true})`. From React's component documentation:

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it's invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.

Here's the [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render) to the React documentation on the render function.

Comment: Your first suggestion is correct, but your second isnt. If you dont provide brackets on an arrow function it will implicitly return. so `.then(response => response.json())` is the same as `.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})`

Comment: @MattAft @Andrew what are other reasons for this Error? for me its showing "Attempted to update component `SmallSpinner` that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount)." but i am not doing setState in render function

Answer (score 2):

There is another way this error can occur...thinking that props are individual arguments (props is actually a single argument)

```
import React from 'react';

const Posts = posts => {       // WRONG

const Posts = ({posts}) => {   // RIGHT
  const renderPosts = () => {
    return posts.map(post => <div>{post.title}</div>);
  };

  return <div>{renderPosts()}</div>;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the asked question, but this is the #1 result for that error on google so this is here as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

My problem is I forget

```
import React from 'react'
```

in my `.jsx` file, since I thought importing React is not needed in functional component.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in Sider, Then inside Link tag I did misspell instead of /location I wrote /locaion .

```
 <Menu.Item key="2">
      <Icon type="settings" />
      <span><Link style={styles.linkStyle} to="/locations">Locations</Link></span>
    </Menu.Item>
```